# PHPWord Repeat template tag replacement inside one document

Tags: php, phpword

I have a word document template file and variables to fill it with(using mysql) but I don't know how to repeat the process over and over again until the mysql while process stops which is when it'd save the file and allow the user to download it.
For example:
WORD DOCUMENT GENERATED:
Filled Template
Filled Template
Filled Template
Filled Template
END DOCUMENT
Allow user to download file.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to replace some variables with contents from the database. You can do something like this:

```
$results=mysql_query(YOUR QUERY HERE);
$template='Some contents of the template';
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($results)){
   $template=str_replace($row['template_variable'], $row['value_for_this_template'], $template);
}
echo $template; //template now has the new values stored in the mysql database
```

Then you will have your template with the mysql values in it. This assumes that you have a mysql table column 'template_variable' that corresponds to something initially in the template file and that the desired value for that particular output of the template is in 'value_for_this_template'.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry, but I meant that the template is actually a word document and the handling procedure for the replacing is handled by the PHPWord scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It  will help you  http://phpword.codeplex.com/discussions/254789  there is a function wich includes to template.php on PHPWord library